# Cannot ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, alter-table, errors

I have a particular table that I cannot add a key for:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tasks ADD KEY `fruitful_user_count` (`user_id`, `is_fruitful`);
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'tasks'; try to repair it
```

Googling the issue it seems that this problem is **often either a configuration issue or a disk space issue**. In fact, this database is running on an [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) instance, which means that it is basically a managed server dedicated to MySQL with a  very standard configuration. Also, the disk allocated to us is only about 25% full.

Considering that perhaps there disk on the VM (powered by Xen I believe) is full, and not my allocated disk space which is likely not even in the same room (network storage), I rebooted the RDS instance in the hope that I would get a new instance on another VM. However, that did not help.

**What should be my next troubleshooting step?**

This is the table:

```
mysql> show create table tasks;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tasks | CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`user_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
`module_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_successful` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_fruitful` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_run` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_pulled` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`module_id`),
KEY `phone_scrapes_user` (`user_id`),
KEY `phone_scrapes_module` (`module_id`),
KEY `urgency` (`last_pulled`,`last_run`),
KEY `successful_user_count` (`user_id`,`is_successful`),
KEY `is_successful` (`is_successful`),
KEY `fruitness` (`is_fruitful`,`is_successful`),
CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: FWIW, rebooting an RDS instance shouldn't be expected to move it to new hardware.  Another approach would be to take a snapshot of the database, restore to a *new* instance of the same size, and try the `ALTER TABLE` there, on the clone, to see what happens.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thank you. I understand that rebooting an EC2 instance does move it, so I assumed that is valid for RDS as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to repair the table:

```sql
mysql> LOCK TABLES `fruitful_user_count` WRITE;
mysql> CREATE TABLE `fruitful_user_count_new` LIKE `fruitful_user_count`;
mysql> INSERT INTO `fruitful_user_count_new` SELECT * FROM `fruitful_user_count`;
mysql> RENAME TABLE `fruitful_user_count` TO `fruitful_user_count_old`;
mysql> RENAME TABLE `fruitful_user_count_new` TO `fruitful_user_count`;
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact I did try this. I could make the new table, but in populating it I get the error `he table 'replacement_tasks' is full`.

Comment: maybe there is no enough disk space?

Comment: Yes, I think so too. However the console shows that there is space. I've now filed an issue with Amazon support.

Comment: Sure enough, the issue was disk space. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Suggested solutions:

1. Execute the following command `REPAIR TABLE table_name;`
2. If that (step one) doesn't help try to change the temp directory in
   the `cnf` file to new location with bigger space;
3. If step one and two did not help you need to restore the database to
   previous stage.

Comment: Thank you. When I try to repair the table I get the message `The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`. And since this is a managed server in RDS, I cannot access the configuration file.

Comment: in-fact even for innodb you need cnf file and add the following line 'innodb_force_recovery = 4' if you can not access the cnf file can you please ask Amazon support to add the line for you, otherwise I guess you need to restore the database

Answer (score 1):

When we are doing Alter on innodb  the "tmpdir" need to be observed.  The Erro 1034 : Key repair is definetly because of "tmpdir" full, and your alter will throw the error.  So I suggest when the Alter is got triggered give one more eye on your "tmpdir" utilization.  If tmp is using 100% there you can see this error for sure :).